# Chrome on Mac: Scrollbars disappear when using `position: sticky`

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, sticky

Please note: **This issue is only happening in Chrome on Mac.**

When a child of a scrollable container is set to `position: sticky;` the scrollbars of the scrollable element are no longer visible.

I have tried to set the `z-index` values for `::-webkit-scrollbar` rules, but that doesn't seem to work. I also thought this was a `z-index` issue with the child elements, but in this example, the child elements have no background set, and would still show the scrollbar underneath them.

In my System Preferences, I have set to "Show scroll bars" to "When scrolling"

How can I get the scrollbars to show up in Chrome on Mac?

```css
.StickyContainer {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 350px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.StickyContainer__box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="StickyContainer">
  <div class="StickyContainer__box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="StickyContainer__box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="StickyContainer__box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="StickyContainer__box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="StickyContainer__box">Box 5</div>
  <div class="StickyContainer__box">Box 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am in Chrome on Mac and, for what it's worth, the snippet above shows scrollbars for me.

Comment: @JeremyHarris, interesting. Do you have your scroll bars set to "Always" under your general system preferences?

Comment: Mine is set to "Automatically based on mouse or trackpad"

Comment: If you have a mouse with a scroll wheel, you will always see the scrollbars when "Automatically based on mouse or trackpad" is selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bug report on Chromium issue tracking website:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033712

The problem has been confirmed and currently under investigation.

For now, you can add `will-change:transform` to the parent element to workaround this problem.

Comment: Ha, yeah, this is the bug I logged with Chromium. I forgot to update here. But what you have provided is correct.